# Adding a number to an element within a listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have to create an application that allows me to subtract the number 1 from each element in the array and display it in the list box using the `for...next` statement.

Here is what I have so far.

```vb
Private intQuantities() As Integer = {45, 67, 2, 5, 90}

Dim intnum2 As Integer = intQuantities.Length

For intCount As Integer = 0 To 4
    lstQuantities.Items.Add(intQuantities(intCount))
    intCount = intCount + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things standout in your code.

The first is that you are never decrementing your `intQuantities` variable before you add it to your listbox. The second is that you are incrementing your index inside your `for` statement which will cause you to skip values.

Try something like this:

```vb
Dim intnum2 As Integer = intQuantities.Length
For intCount As Integer = 0 To 4
    intQuantities(intCount) -= 1  'This will subtract one and store it back to the array
    lstQuantities.Items.Add(intQuantities(intCount))
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I was somewhat on the right track, just couldn't figure out a few pieces. Once again thanks. I still have a ways to go in learning this.

Answer (score 0):

```
lstQuantities.Items.Add(intQuantities(intCount) - 1)
```